# Getting several buttons to stay active when the page refreshes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, session-storage

I've been working on a table for a class project for awhile, and it is working pretty well (thanks to a lot of contributions I found here)

I am having problems getting buttons to stay active when the page is reloaded. I am using jQuery, and have worked with `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` quite a bit without results. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the snippet:

```js
  function toggle(event) { //this is what happens when you click on a button
      $(this).toggleClass('active'); //adds an "active" class (color changes)
      sessionStorage.setItem("activeDiv", $(this).index('.btn')); //i need help with this
    }
    $(function() {
        "use strict";
        $(".btn").on("click ", toggle); // you can set the buttons active or not
          var activebtn = sessionStorage.getItem("activeDiv"); 
          if (activebtn) {                                      //I need help with this
            $('.btn').toggleClass('active').eq(activebtn).toggleClass('active');
          }
        });
```

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  background-color: #a3bfd9;
  border: solid 2px #41403E;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.btn {
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #ebd3eb;
  border-color: #93e2ff;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #93e2ff;
  opacity: 0.7;
  /*color: #5fc0e3;*/
  border-color: #5fc0e3;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.btn.active {
  background-color: #899c30;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #005fbf;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="obsimotable">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
        <br>
        <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
        <br>
        <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
        <br>
        <button class="btn" value="5">Some class 5op</button>
        <br>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
        <br>
        <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
        <br>
        <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
        <br>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
        <br>
        <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
        <br>
        <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
        <br>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn" value="5">Some class 5op</button>
        <br>
        <button class="btn" value="13">Some class 13op</button>
        <br>
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="btn" value="5">Some class 5op</button>
        <br>
        <button class="btn" value="5">Some class 5op</button>
        <br>
        <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
        <br>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
        <br>
        <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
        <br>
        <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
        <br>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
        <br>
        <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
        <br>
        <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
        <br>
        <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
        <br>
        <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
        <br>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn" value="6">Some class 6op</button>
        <br>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
        <br>
        <button class="btn" value="6">Some class 6op</button>
        <br>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
        <br>
        <button class="btn" value="6">Some class 6op</button>
        <br>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn" value="6">Some class 6op</button>
        <br>
        <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
        <br>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
        <br>
        <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
        <br>
        <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
        <br>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
        <br>
        <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
        <br>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
        <br>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: You would need to save an array containing all indexes of the selected buttons. Session storage can only hold strings. You would need to JSON stringify your array to store the values as a string. On reloading you need to parse that string and check which button needs to be toggled and handle selecting/unselecting an item... so that sounds a lot more complex than what you are doing in the code you shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my earlier comment, one way would be to use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` as you need to store multiple values (multiple buttons), but local (and session) storage only allows to save strings.

Code is commented so it should be easy to understand what is going on.

```
function toggle(event) {

  let btnIndex = $(this).index('.btn');
  let activeButtons = [];

  if (!sessionStorage.getItem("activeButtons")) {

    // Session storage item doesn't exist yet -> Create it
    sessionStorage.setItem("activeButtons", JSON.stringify(activeButtons));
  }

  // Get active buttons from session storage
  activeButtons = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("activeButtons"));

  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {

    // Button has active class -> Remove from activeButtons array
    var index = activeButtons.indexOf(btnIndex);
    if (index !== -1) activeButtons.splice(index, 1);

  } else {

    // Button doesn't have active class -> Push to activeButtons array
    activeButtons.push(btnIndex);
  }

  // Toggle active class
  $(this).toggleClass('active');

  // Set items in session storage
  sessionStorage.setItem("activeButtons", JSON.stringify(activeButtons));
}

$(function() {

  //sessionStorage.clear(); // Uncomment this line to clear session storage

  $(".btn").on("click ", toggle);

  // Load active buttons
  let activeButtons = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("activeButtons"));

  if (activeButtons.length) {

    // Loop through active buttons
    for (var i = 0; i < activeButtons.length; i++) {

      // Add active class for each active button
      $('.btn').eq(activeButtons[i]).addClass('active');
    }
  }
});
```

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/3d7vcb08/).

Comment: Oh wow. I did sort of get something from setting a cookie and calling the cookies on reload, but this makes a lot more sense!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution: https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/vQjYGw?editors=1011

This is in a codepen, because the SO snippets don't allow to use sessionStorage (for apparent reasons).

Anyway the JS code is like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  "use strict";
  var activeButtons = []
  var selector = '.btn';
  var storageKey = "activeButtons";
  var activeClassName = 'active';

  readStorage();
  $(selector).on('click', reactClick);

  function readStorage() {
    var storage = sessionStorage.getItem(storageKey);
    if (storage) {
      activeButtons = storage.split(',');
    }
    $(selector)
      .filter(function(i, e) {
        return activeButtons.indexOf(""+i) !== -1
      })
      .toggleClass(activeClassName)
  }

  function reactClick() {
    $(this).toggleClass(activeClassName);
    var index = $(this).index(selector);
    toggleArrayItem(activeButtons, ""+index);
    sessionStorage.setItem(storageKey, activeButtons)
  }

  function toggleArrayItem(a, v) {
      var i = a.indexOf(v);
      if (i === -1)
          a.push(v);
      else
          a.splice(i,1);
  }  

});
```